# Hot espresso poured into a cold cup - is that dangerous?

Tags: coffee, espresso

When making a flavored iced drink - for example a mocha - what is the correct steps to take in order to make the best drink. Is it ok to pour the hot espresso over the measured amount of chocolate at the bottom of a cold cup ?

Comment: Do you have specific concerns about the process or the outcome? You mention several topics. As for "cold cup," you might be concerned about the temperature change (e.g., I personally find that espresso in cold drinks tastes bad). You might also be concerned about order: pouring hot espresso over the chocolate, versus putting chocolate into the espresso (I'd suggest the latter because it will melt/mix better). What do you mean by "dangerous" in this sense? Also consider asking coffee-specific questions over at the [coffee.se] Stack Exchange site!

Comment: @hoc_age I edited the question to remove off-topic parts. The original ending was about health-related stuff (toxins in plastic) so I snipped it.

Answer (score 2):

There are frequently conflicting opinions about coffee preparation, as everyone has their own way that they like it best. Keep in mind that these are just opinions though and you should prepare the drink however it most appeals to you.

That said, there are a few things to keep in mind: If you're using solid chocolate or cocoa powder, you'd want to add hot liquid directly to that to melt it. Most flavorings will dissolve best in hot liquid, but syrups can be stirred in to cold liquids as well. The main thing you'd want to avoid is pouring hot liquid directly over ice, as that will water down your coffee a lot. Generally my method is to pour the espresso over the syrup, swirl it to dissolve, add cold milk, then add ice last. If I'm making an iced Americano, I do add the espresso directly to ice and then omit adding water (or reduce the water).

Comment: When you say cocoa powder do you mean instant cocoa mix or something? Pure cocoa powder doesn't really dissolve well, hot liquid or not.

Comment: Good points... and please consider joining us at [coffee.se]! :-D

Comment: @Jefromi cocoa powder won't exactly "dissolve", but you can get it to disperse pretty evenly in espresso (especially a fresh shot). I'd say it melts more than dissolves. For an instant mix, I'd still recommend putting it in the hot liquid.

Comment: @sourd'oh Yes, instant mix definitely works best when it's hot. I've seen cocoa powder clump pretty badly even in hot liquid, so I'm surprised to hear you can get it to work well in an espresso shot!

Answer (score 0):

My gift to you. Use a martini shaker. Measure your chocolate sauce into the martini shaker cup. Add hot brewed espresso or fresh brewed double strength coffee. Let this rest for 15 seconds. Then, add good amount of ice, cover and shake for about 30 seconds.  Add ice to a serving glass and pour the mocha from the martini shaker over ice. Top with milk and serve with a straw.